# LWJGL texture does not render

Tags: java, graphics, rendering, lwjgl

I've been trying to write a game engine in lwjgl and I've come across an issue with rendering and I'd like a bit of help. Basically, I've followed some steps in the lwjgl-basics (mattdesl on GitHub) and produced a Texture class and a section in my renderer that work except that they don't render a texture. Here's the code...

```
public void drawTexturedRectangle(float x1, float y1, float w, float h, Texture t){
        t.bind();
        GL11.glColor4f(1.0f, 0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x1, y1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x1 + w, y1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x1 + w, y1 + h);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x1, y1 + h);
        GL11.glEnd();
    }
```

That's where it renders. Here's the Texture class:

```
package com.nightfall.morningside;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import de.matthiasmann.twl.utils.*;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12.*;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;

public class Texture {
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int id;

    public Texture(URL pathToTexture){
        try {
            InputStream pngstream = pathToTexture.openStream();
            PNGDecoder pngdecoder = new PNGDecoder(pngstream);

            width = pngdecoder.getWidth();
            height = pngdecoder.getHeight();

            int bpp = 4;

            ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(bpp * width * height);

            pngdecoder.decode(buffer, width * bpp, PNGDecoder.Format.RGBA);

            buffer.flip();

            id = GL11.glGenTextures();

            GL11.glPixelStorei(GL11.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void bind(){
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    }
}
```

The TexturedRectangle class:

```
package com.nightfall.morningside.geometry;

import com.nightfall.morningside.Texture;
import com.nightfall.morningside.Textured;

public class TexturedRectangle extends Rectangle implements Textured{
    public Texture texture;

    public TexturedRectangle(float xone, float yone, float w, float h, Texture t) {
        super(xone, yone, w, h);
        texture = t;
    }

    public Texture getTexture() {
        return texture;
    }

}
```

The Rectangle class:

```
package com.nightfall.morningside.geometry;

public class Rectangle {
    private float x1;
    private float y1;
    private float width;
    private float height;

    public Rectangle(float xone, float yone, float w, float h){
        x1 = xone;
        y1 = yone;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public float getX1(){
        return x1;
    }

    public float getY1(){
        return y1;
    }

    public float getHeight(){
        return height;
    }

    public float getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

    public Point getLocation(){
        return new Point(x1, y1);
    }
}
```

And the Textured interface:

```
package com.nightfall.morningside;

public interface Textured {
    public Texture getTexture();
}
```

And the Point class:

```
package com.nightfall.morningside.geometry;

public class Point {
    private float x1;
    private float y1;

    public Point(float x, float y){
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;
    }

    public float getX(){
        return x1;
    }

    public float getY(){
        return y1;
    }
}
```

I hope this is everything. I believe it's an issue in the way I'm rendering but maybe there's an issue in where I load textures.
If you need anything else, I'll put it up for you.
Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and just to clarify, it's with lwjgl 2.90

Comment: If you're making an engine, then don't use all the deprecated OpenGL methods.

Comment: I'm only doing it to learn - I'll replace everything as soon as I am sure I can actually do it at all.

Comment: Well it's good for learning, though don't replace everything when you've learned it make a new engine, since replacing every deprecated method would be a nightmare. Here are some of the deprecated methods `glMatrixMode`, `glLoadIdentity`, `glTranslate`, `glRotate`, `glScale`, `glBegin`, `glEnd`, `glVertex`, `glNormal`, `glTexCoord`, `glColor`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Texture are disable by default. When you want to render a textured primitive (a textured quad for instance), you must activate texturing with

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
```

The first line tells openGL to use texturing, the second specify which texture you want to use.

To stop using the texture, you can:

- Bind zero to GL_TEXTURE_2D : `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);`   **or**
- Disable GL_TEXTURE_2D : `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`

edit, I forgot all the `GLxx.` prefixes (static import in my codes)

Comment: You can't just give `glBindTexture` 0 as the handle, you need to give it an actual handle.

Comment: Actualy you can, it is now deprecated, but it means unbind the texture. OP uses immediate mode, glBindTexture(X, 0) is imo acceptable, works fine, and even solves problems for me. See http://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/glBindTexture.html.

Comment: Ohh I though you told him that was the way to bind the texture, I didn't see/think that you where implying how to unbind it, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Hmmm. I reread my post, and it's extremely confusing. You're right! I'll edit it!